# Which version of sqoop should I use for hadoop 3.3.0?

Tags: windows, hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to install sqoop 1.4.7 in windows 10 on hadoop 3.3.0 ,

on using **./configure-sqoop** on GIT bash I get following o/p:

Warning: C:\sqoop_data\sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: C:\sqoop_data\sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: C:\sqoop_data\sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: C:\sqoop_data\sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.

on verifying the installation using **sqoop.cmd version** ,  I get:

Warning: HBASE_HOME and HBASE_VERSION not set.
Warning: HCAT_HOME not set
Warning: HCATALOG_HOME does not exist HCatalog imports will fail.
Please set HCATALOG_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: ACCUMULO_HOME not set.
Warning: ZOOKEEPER_HOME not set.
Warning: HBASE_HOME does not exist HBase imports will fail.
Please set HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: ACCUMULO_HOME does not exist Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: ZOOKEEPER_HOME does not exist Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
**The system cannot find the path specified.**

Please help with a solution to this problem

Answer (score 1):

it depends if you are working on a server-side or client-side.

If you are on the server-side do the following:

Copy the Sqoop artifact to the machine where you want to run Sqoop server. The Sqoop server acts as a Hadoop client, therefore Hadoop libraries (Yarn, Mapreduce, and HDFS jar files) and configuration files (core-site.xml, mapreduce-site.xml, ...) must be available on this node. You do not need to run any Hadoop related services - running the server on a “gateway” node is perfectly fine.

## Decompress Sqoop distribution tarball

```
tar -xvf sqoop-<version>-bin-hadoop<hadoop-version>.tar.gz
```

## Move decompressed content to any location

```
mv sqoop-<version>-bin-hadoop<hadoop version>.tar.gz /usr/lib/sqoop
```

## Change working directory

```
cd /usr/lib/sqoop
```

And sqoopt needs the enviromantal variables to be poiting at Hadoop libraries. So set and export the variables like that:

```
# Export HADOOP_HOME variable
export HADOOP_HOME=/...

# Or alternatively HADOOP_*_HOME variables
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/...
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/...
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/...
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=/...
```

Sqoop server will need to impersonate users to access HDFS, so edit the core-site.xml file:

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.sqoop2.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.sqoop2.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
```

For client installation
Just copy Sqoop distribution artifact on target machine and unzip it in desired location. You can start client with following command:

```
sqoop2-shell
```

for the path variable, All user and administrator facing shell commands are stored in bin/ directory. It’s recommended to add this directory to your $PATH for easier execution, for example:

```
PATH=$PATH:`pwd`/bin/
```

Comment: Does it work? Is it possible to use Sqoop 1.4.7 with Hadoop 3.X+?

Answer (score 0):

This combination works well for me:

- Hadoop: 3.3.1
- Sqoop: 1.4.7
- Connector/J: 5.1.49

> Note:
> You must replaced "commons-lang3-3.4.jar" by "commons-lang-2.6.jar" in "$SQOOP_HOME/lib" to avoid error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils" when using "Sqoop import".